# zebra look: alternating lines in the list (no hover)

Tags: react-admin

as in the example shown, the rowStyle should be used. the lines from the list should be colored alternately. this also works, but the hover color is no longer shown :-(

```
const postRowStyle = (record, index) => ({
  backgroundColor: index % 2 ? "#cdcdcd" : ""
});
export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowStyle={postRowStyle}>
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

what needs to be done so that the hover comes again?
THX

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigorous-dubinsky-n2sx0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of react-admin, you can use makeStyles to modify styles of alternating rows in the Datagrid:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Datagrid } from 'react-admin';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  rowEven: {
    backgroundColor: '#cdcdcd',
  },
  rowOdd: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default (props: any) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Datagrid {...props} classes={classes}>
      {props.children}
    </Datagrid>
  );
}
```

You can then use the styled Datagrid component in your lists, instead of the original. Hover will continue to work.

See CSS API here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html

For the full set of available element selectors, check the source code here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/useDatagridStyles.tsx